# Angular 4 @HostBinding('attr.id') does not work (undefined)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have difficulties binding to host element 'id' attribute in my select-picker directive. I am using `@HostBinding('attr.id')`, but it returns `undefined`. I have checked the actual DOC and it looks like this is the way this simple task should be done.

**Here is my component**:

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';
declare const $;

@Component({
    selector: '[select-picker]',
    templateUrl: 'select-picker.component.html'
})

export class SelectPickerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @Input() options: Array<Object>;
    @Input() @HostBinding('class.cancelable') cancelable: boolean;
    @Input() @HostBinding('class.expand-up') expandUp: boolean;
    @Input() @HostBinding('style.width') elemWidth: string;
    @HostBinding('attr.id') id: string;

    @Output() value: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    select: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.id) // <-- this logs 'undefined';
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const self = this;
        this.select = $(`#${this.id} select`).selectize({ // this init works, but with `id="undefined"`
            readOnly: true,
            onChange: function (val) {
                self.value.emit(val);
            },
            dropdownDirection: 'up'
        });
    }

    discardValue() {
        this.select[0].selectize.setValue(0);
    }
}
```

**And this is the view (from parent component where directive is used):**

```
<div select-picker id="page-options" [options]="pageOptions" [elemWidth]="'200px'" (value)="setItemsPerPage($event)"></div>
```

Comment: is this attr.id a static element? or you generate it dynamiclly?

Comment: I just want to grab static value of the host 'id' attribute for the purpose of later use in jQuery lib init (and not to use constructor (@Attribute())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute binding for static values can also be done with simple:

```
@Input() id: string;
```

Both versions - `<div id="some-static-id" ...>` and `<div [id]="someDynamicId" ...>` - will set the value on your component when using `@Input()`.

**EDIT: However**, it is strongly discouraged to use jQuery and lookup by IDs in Angular. I would question if your approach is the best option to accomplish what you want. You should probably create a separate question where you explain what you try to accomplish and what is the best way to do this with Angular.

Comment: yes, but I want this to correspond later to html id attribute to use in jQuery snippet, and I don't want to type it twice

Comment: So just use `<div id="some-static-id">` and  `@Input() id: string;` in your component.

Comment: Wow, didn't know it is simple as that. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, it is strongly discouraged to use jQuery and lookup by IDs in Angular. I would question if your approach is the best option to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I will need a decent level of customization for each such element, that said unique lib init for each. What is your suggestion if you don't mind?

Comment: This shouldn't be the correct answer. Actually, none of this answer properly address the issue here: @HostBinding(attr) = undefined when it should return the real value

Answer (score 2):

You could directly retrieve attribute value of element using `getAttribute` method on directive DOM. This will only work when you have static element `id`. If you want to pass `id` dynamically, use `Input` bindings.

```
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){}
ngOnInit() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')
}
```

[**Plunker Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/mgiqrDsdAO1nZz7nwo4X?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab a Id value just use @ViewChild not @HostBinding

```
<div #myDiv></div>


@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;
```

console.log(this.myDiv.nativeElement.id)

and then use methods of ElementRef do get id attribute